# How to change scene in Scene Kit?

Tags: ios, macos, sprite-kit, scenekit, scene

How can we change the scene in Scene Kit? Because scenes behave differently in Scene Kit and Sprite Kit.

Why can't we do it like we do in Sprite Kit?

```
var scene:SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size);
self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: nil);
```

I want to create multiple scenes in Scene Kit like Menu Scene (2D menu), Game Scene (3D scene), Options Scene (2D menu), Main Menu Scene(2D menu). What's the best way to do this? (Some 2D scenes and some 3D scenes).

Answer (score 3):

You *can* do it the way you do in SpriteKit, but the calls are slightly different.

In iOS 8 and OS X up to 10.10, set the view's [`scene`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/scene) property. (There's no transition effect like is SpriteKit.)

In iOS 9 and OS X 10.11, you can add a transition by calling the view's [`presentScene:withTransition:incomingPointOfView:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SCNSceneRenderer/presentScene:withTransition:incomingPointOfView:completionHandler:) method.

A SceneKit view (`SCNView`) presents only SceneKit scenes (`SCNScene`). But if you want to switch back and forth between 2D and 3D scenes, you can still do that... Just set the [`overlaySKScene`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524051-overlayskscene) property of your view.

Comment: How can you change the content of `overlaySKScene` in a smooth way, to transition from one SKScene to another?

Comment: I’m also wondering about transitions between different scenes in overlaySKScene — did you find an answer?